# How does this motor work?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, design, solenoid, actuator

I have been on a bit of a quest to find some sort of linear motion device to compress a spring with 15kg of force 80mm at 1600mm/s, with continuous duty cycle, ideally under $40. So I was digging for some sort of device and found [this linear motor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz-aDJzDEvE). However it seems very overkill, I need less than half the speed and less than half the stroke length, with the stroke only acting in one direction. I need no where near the amount of precision(I only need +/- 2.5mm precision where is this is +/- 1μm precise I think), and only 150N (although 200N would be nice) of force.

Does anyone know how this device works and can anyone adapt the design for my need so I can build it for a fraction of the price (and power[I think this uses 48V with 6A continuous current])?

Anything between 12 and 24v would be nice.

I plan on "DIY-ing" it, buying the necessary parts. I have looked at [linear actuators](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55965/high-speed-linear-actuator-motor-design), but they seem too slow and solenoids but my stroke length seems [too great](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/676772/strong-compact-solenoid-design/676799) and even tried designing my [own actuator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/676956/linear-motor-design?noredirect=1#comment1802681_676956) with a series of solenoids.

Comment: This is your third question on the same matter in a few days, all with slightly different wording. Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/676956/linear-motor-design

Comment: “Fraction of the price” can only work if your time is free. A geared motor with a crank output would do the job. Two of them for mechanical simplicity - looking at the top of the spring, one at 9-o’clock, another at 3-o’clock. The rockers then grab the top of the spring on each side. The motor output shafts would need index sensors to determine travel endpoints so they can always start at the same position and stop at the same position. The stroke can be open-loop, perhaps compensate by adapting the drive voltage of one motor to match the stroke timing of the other motor.

Comment: @winny Yeah, I linked them in the question in the last line, I was trying to figure out how [this works, even though it is for the same project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz-aDJzDEvE). What do you suggest that I should do when I have a development such as this?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica do you have a diagram of sorts for this?